# How do you show that a Hilbert space is separable if and only if it has a countable dense subset?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, separable-spaces

I know that, by definition, a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ is separable if there exists a countable subset $X$ such that $\operatorname{span}(X)$ is dense in $\mathscr{H}$.

I want to prove that $\mathscr{H}$ is separable if and only if there exists a countable and dense subset.

I know I have to try with combinations like "$p+iq$" with $p$ and $q$ rational, but I can't find the way.

Comment: You have it backwards: what you call "definition" is a theorem and what you want to prove is the definition of separability (which is a property of topological spaces, not necessarily of complex normed vector spaces).

Answer (score 4):

First off, just for the sake of clarity, the relevant definitions:

> A topological space is said to be *separable* if it contains a countable dense subset.  In other words, $X$ is separable if there exists a countable subset $\{x_n\}$ such that if $U \subseteq X$ is open and nonempty, then $U \cap \{x_n\} \ne \emptyset$.

The theorem, then, is that a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ is separable if and only if there is some countable set $\{e_n\}\subseteq \mathscr{H}$ such that $\mathscr{H} = \overline{\operatorname{span}(\{e_n\})}$.  Again, for clarity, note that the span of a set is the collection of all *finite* linear combinations of elements of that set, and by taking the closure, we get infinite linear combinations.  This is equivalent to the statement that there is some subset of $\mathscr{H}$ which has a dense span in $\mathscr{H}$ (i.e. your original statement).  In other words, 
$$ \mathscr{H} = \overline{\operatorname{span}(\{e_n\})} = \overline{\left\{ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \lambda_j e_j \ \middle|\  \lambda_j \in \mathbb{F}, e_j\in\{e_n\} \right\}}, $$
where $\mathbb{F}$ is the base field (we will assume that $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$—we'll use the fact that the base field is separable, and other fields (such as $\mathbb{C}$) can get the job done, but the generalization is not too hard to come by, so we'll stick with the assumption that $\mathscr{H}$ is a real Hilbert space).

For the forward implication, suppose that $\mathscr{H} = \overline{\operatorname{span}(\{e_n\})}$, where $\{e_n\}$ is countable. Since $\operatorname{span}(\{e_n\})$ is dense in $\mathscr{H}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that
$$ \left\{ \sum_{j=1}^{k} q_j e_k \ \middle|\ q_j \in \mathbb{Q}, e_j\in \{x_n\}, k \in\mathbb{N} \right\} $$
is a countable dense subset of $\mathscr{H}$ (this statement requires some proof, but is certainly doable—I'll leave it as an exercise).  Hence $\mathscr{H}$ is separable.

For the reverse implication, suppose that $\mathscr{H}$ is separable.  Then there exists a countable set $\{x_n\}\subseteq\mathscr{H}$ that is dense in $\mathscr{H}$.  But
$$ \{x_n\} \subseteq \operatorname{span}(\{x_n\}), $$
and so it follows from the density of $\{x_n\}$ that $\operatorname{span}(\{x_n\})$ is *also* dense in $\mathscr{H}$, which completes the argument.  Or, if you prefer, we could apply the [Gram-Schmidt procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to $\{x_n\}$ in order to obtain an orthonormal set with dense span.

Comment: The$(x_n)$ aren't necessarily linear independent, how do we apply Gram-Schmidt to it?

Comment: @DanielPlácido The usual setup for the Gram-Schmidt procedure is a *finite* collection of *linearly independent* vectors which span a space.  The result of the process is a collection of vectors which are mutually orthogonal. The vectors are produced by recursively defining $$ y_k = x_k - \sum_{j=1}^{k} \operatorname{proj}_{y_j}(x_k). $$  If $x_k$ is not linearly independent of the previous $y_j$, then the result of this computation will be the zero vector. The result of the Gram-Schmidt process will be a collection of independent, mutually orthogonal vectors, and the zero vector.

Comment: Note, also, that the initial collection of vectors is countably infinite, so there is also an extra step involved here, e.g. some kind of transfinite induction.

Comment: So just drop the zero vectors along the way. Makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look at all rational linear combinations of vectors in your countable set. This set is still countable since $\mathbb{Q}$ is. But it is dense in its span.